# button clicked image windows phone development

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I have recently taken up windows phone development, I'd like to create custom button states, one for button and one for button pressed, I have searched over the net for a solution and there are many but most are convoluted and require a tedious amount of work for something that should be simple.

I have two images, one for button and one for pressed how can I implement this in visual studio c#?

Comment: What part do you find tedious? Overriding the default brush in the VisualStateManager, or something else?

Comment: Expression blend is a better tool for you in this scenario.